# how to print unique data from database in sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm building a libary management system in python using tkinter and sqlite3. made some entry widgets for the user to input book_id, book_name and author:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1350x750')

entry_id_book = Entry(root, width=30)
entry_id_book.pack()

entry_book_name = Entry(root, width=30)
entry_book_name.pack()

entry_author = Entry(root, width=30)
entry_author.pack()
```

connect to a database

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('library.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (
        id_book int PRIMARY KEY,
        book_name text,
        author text
)""")

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

and a treeview widget where I'll display the data

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, show='headings')

tree['columns'] = ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Author')

tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=0, anchor=CENTER)
tree.column('Book ID', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
tree.column('Book Name', anchor=CENTER, width=250)
tree.column('Author', anchor=CENTER, width=150)

tree.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('Book ID', text='Book ID', anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('Book Name', text='Book Name', anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('Author', text='Author', anchor=CENTER)

tree.pack()
```

a function to take those inputs and load the data into the database

```
def load_data():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('library.db')    
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('INSERT INTO books VALUES(:id_book, :book_name, :author)',    
              {
                  'id_book': entry_id_book.get(),
                  'book_name': entry_book_name.get(),
                  'author': entry_author.get()
              })
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

and another function to print those into a treeview widget

```
def display_data():
   conn = sqlite3.connect('library.db')
   c = conn.cursor()

   c.execute('SELECT * FROM books')
   list_book = c.fetchall()
   for book in list_book:
        tree.insert('', END, values=book)

   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
```

the buttons for the 2 functions above:

```
bt_load = Button(root, text='Load', command=load_data)
bt_load.pack()

bt_display = Button(root, text='Display', command=display_data)
bt_display.pack()
```

It will load and display those books just fine:

```
Book ID                   Book Name                     Author
```

[image]

but when I load a new book into the database and press Display button one more time, it will show me duplicates of all the other previous book data plus the new one:

```
Book ID                   Book Name                     Author
```

[image]

I know there must be something wrong with my for loop in the display_data function, but I suck at programming logic so I can't figure out what's wrong with it. How can I display each different line only once?

Comment: I think your issue is, you don't reset the tree before repopulating it with all your database entries. What you could try to do is empty the `tree` inside your `display_data` before you populate it again.

Comment: The table name in `CREATE TABLE` statement is `books`, but the name use in `load_data()` is `book` (without trailing `s`).  Also the database name and table name are completely different in `display_data()`.

Comment: you can also look DISTINCT keyword for example `c.execute('SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM livros')`

Comment: First `print(lista_livros)` and make sure you have what you expect it to be(without duplication), then proceed to look at comments above.

Comment: oops I had to translate the code written in portugues (I'm a brazilian) to english to post it here. Guess I overlooked this part. livro means book and lista_livros was supposed to be list_book

Comment: empty the tree? That... makes sense. So each time a new data is loaded I should reset the tree before printing the books data? Guess the code for that should be added to display_data function. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: First `print()` the records and make sure it does not have duplication, if it has duplication, something is wrong with your insertion.